# Creating pivot table to show counts and add missing months as columns

Tags: sql, pivot, presto, amazon-athena

Original Table

```
id month
1  10/2017
1  10/2017
1  11/2017
2  1/2017
2  3/2017
3  9/2016
3  9/2016
3  5/2017
3  6/2017
3  6/2017
3  10/2017
```

Updated Table:

```
id  9/2016 10/2016 11/2016 12/2016 1/2017 2/2017 3/2017 4/2017 5/2017 6/2017 7/2017 8/2017 9/2017 10/2017 11/2017
1   0      0       0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2       1
2   0      0       0       0       1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0
3   2      0       0       0       0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      1       0
```

I typically use python and pandas so I'm not sure how to do this in SQL.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update to Query:

```
select
    sum(case when quarter = '2006-07-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2006Q3',
    sum(case when quarter = '2006-10-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2006Q4',
    sum(case when quarter = '2007-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2007Q1',
    sum(case when quarter = '2007-04-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2007Q2',
...
from trans_v3
group by core_id
```

Comment: SQL is statically typed language. The set of columns needs to be known before the query starts executing. This means, you will need to embed this information in your query. (Like in @kjmerf answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could brute force it:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN month = '9/2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 201609
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month = '10/2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 201610
...
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I changed the column name a bit but I'm getting the following error: `mismatched input ''2016q3''`. I'm not sure whats going on here.

Comment: Can you share the whole query?

Comment: I assume you figured out the issue?